# Days between two dates In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using

```
DATEDIFF(d, @Date, @ExDate) as T
```

to get the number of days between `@Date` and `@ExDate`. I got the number of days. But I want to the fraction T/365 for some calculation. If I do this I got 0 because it returns the time. What should I do to get that value?

Comment: So simply dividing by 365 doesn't do the trick?

Comment: if it is divided by 365 then i got 0

Comment: Just divide by `365.0`, which will force decimal division.

Comment: Amazing It works,Thanks can u explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT ( DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-11-12', '2016-11-30') ) / 365.00
```

Comment: i got the same thing 0

Comment: post your ran query with data

Comment: What about leap year

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, @Date, @ExDate) / CONVERT(decimal(5,13), 365)
FROM yourTable
```